# Stationary distribution of M/M/∞ queue with customer types

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I'm new to queueing theory but think I have a problem sufficiently well-described by a M/M/∞ queue.  I am seeking to determine the proportion of time that is spent servicing $n$ customers (specifically $n=0$ for an idle/empty queue).  I've learned how to do this for a [M/M/1 queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36393/crowded-and-quiet-periods-in-a-m-m-1-queue?rq=1), but not for a M/M/∞ queue (or for a M/G/∞ queue, which I anticipate desiring eventually).

An additional aspect (for which I have yet to find standard terminology with which to get useful search results) is that I have $r$ different customer types, each having their own arrival rate $\lambda_r$ and service rate $\mu_r$.  In the context of M/M/1 this doesn't seem like it would create too much additional difficulty since, as long as I assume that customer types are independent, the [result of independent Poisson processes is also a Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Sums_of_Poisson-distributed_random_variables) with overall rates $\lambda = \sum_r \lambda_r$ and $\mu = \sum_r \mu_r$. (Is that correct?)

Comment: What do you mean by "the average length of time that $n$ customers are being serviced"? Do you mean "the average length of time until the amount of customers in the system is no longer $n$" or "if $n$ customers are in the system, the average length of time until we reach $n=0$" or "if $n$ customers are in the system, the average length of time until *those* customers are all done (even if new ones arrive)" or something else?

Comment: And no: M/M/1 with $k$ customer types is not equivalent to a standard M/M/1. It's equivalent to an M/G/1 with arrival rate $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_r$, and a service time which is a mixture distribution: it is sampled from $\text{Exp}(\mu_i)$ with probability $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda}$ for $i=1,\dots,r$. Arrivals are still memoryless, but departures aren't.

Comment: I mean the expected time (or proportion of total time $T$) that the system is in the $n^{th}$ state (i.e. with 0, 1, 2, ... customers).  (I will edit my question after confirming that this clarifies what I'm after.)  Is that not the equivalent of asking what the steady state distribution is?  Also, thank you for your first comment pointing out my error of thought regarding the service times.

Comment: *Proportion of total time* is certainly the same thing as the steady-state distribution. Asking about expected time makes me think of hitting times: the time until you reach one state starting from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an M/M/$\infty$ system, each state $n \ge 0$ has a transition to state $n+1$ with a rate of $\lambda$ (the arrival rate), and each state $n \ge 1$ has a transition to state $n-1$ with a rate of $n \mu$ (since there are $n$ customers, each of whom has an $\text{Exp}(\mu)$ service time remaining).

The easiest way to solve for the steady-state probabilities is by using local balance equations. If $\pi_n$ is the fraction of time we are in state $n$, then we have $$\pi_{n-1} \cdot \lambda = \pi_n \cdot (n \mu)$$ for all $n \ge 1$. The left-hand side represents the rate of $n-1 \to n$ transitions; the right-hand side represents the rate of $n \to n-1$ transitions. These rates should be equal because such transitions must alternate: if you step $n-1 \to n$, you can't take another $n-1 \to n$ step until an $n \to n-1$ step occurs.

This leads us to $\pi_n = \frac{\lambda}{n\mu} \pi_{n-1} = \frac{(\lambda/\mu)^n}{n!} \pi_0$ by induction, and even if you're a bit skeptical of the local balance equations, you can verify that this satisfies the stationary equations. Finally,
$$
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n = 1 \implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda/\mu)^n}{n!} \pi_0 = 1 \implies e^{\lambda/\mu} \pi_0 = 1
$$
from which we conclude that $\pi_0 = e^{-\lambda/\mu}$ and $\pi_n = e^{-\lambda/\mu} \frac{(\lambda/\mu)^n}{n!}$. You might recognize this as the probability mass function of a $\text{Poisson}(\lambda/\mu)$ random variable.

---

With $r$ different customer types - actually the M/M/1 queue feels like it would be a nightmare to analyze in that case, but the M/M/$\infty$ is easy. Rather than all the customers arriving into the same M/M/$\infty$ system, we can give each customer type its own M/M/$\infty$ system, and that doesn't change anything because $r$ copies of $\infty$ is still $\infty$. Because no customers ever have to wait in line, no customer ever cares about how many customers of other types there are - so the $r$ individual M/M/$\infty$ systems are independent.

A state of this combined system would be $(n_1, n_2, \dots, n_r)$ where $n_i$ is the number of customers of type $i$ that are currently being serviced. Since the systems are independent, the stationary distribution of the combined system is
$$
    \pi_{n_1, n_2, \dots, n_r} = \prod_{i=1}^r e^{-\lambda_i/\mu_i} \frac{(\lambda_i/\mu_i)^{n_i}}{n_i!}.
$$
Ultimately, you probably want to know a formula for $\pi_n$, the fraction of time there are $n$ total customers. This is no longer the probability of a single state, but a sum over states:
$$
    \pi_n = \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_r = n} \pi_{n_1, n_2, \dots, n_r}.
$$
To our rescue comes the multinomial theorem:
$$
    \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_r = n} \frac{n!}{n_1! n_2! \dotsm n_r!} x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2} \dotsm x_r^{n_r} = (x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_r)^n.
$$
In particular, it implies that $\pi_n = e^{-\rho} \frac{\rho^n}{n!}$ where $\rho = \frac{\lambda_1}{\mu_1} + \frac{\lambda_2}{\mu_2} + \dots + \frac{\lambda_r}{\mu_r}$: it is also Poisson.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense to me.  To complete the answer explicitly, does it then follow, letting $\rho_i = \frac{\lambda_i }{\mu_i}$ for different customer types, that $\pi_0 = e^{-(\rho_1+\rho_2 +...+\rho_r)}$ (with similar substitution of $\rho$'s for $\pi_n$?  Your comment above regarding service times being a mixture distribution causes me to doubt that.

Comment: Also, do you know of standard (like [Kendall's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_notation)) or freqeuntly used terminology with which to reference a queue with multiple customer types (i.e. different arrival times and service rates)?

Comment: (1) I originally got too scared of the $r$-customer-types case, but then I had an insight: though this case is horrible for M/M/1, it is actually doable in M/M/$\infty$ and really does give the "nice" answer you want. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: (2) I believe that the queue with multiple customer types is called a *classed* queue, but I have only seen this kind of thing in multiple-server, multiple-queue networks where service times are the same, but different job types have different behavior after they are processed.

Comment: Regarding (2), yes, post-arrival differentiation of job types is the only context in which I've found something similar as well.

Comment: I just found [Zukerman's book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2968v23) which in Sec. 7.4 (pg 155 in v23) provides references indicating that what @MishaLavrov wrote above for M/M/∞ also applies to M/G/∞, thereby satisfying my final (anticipated) desire as well.